# Why Phoenix always add a extra column (named _0) to hbase when I execute UPSERT command?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

When I execute the **UPSERT** command on apache phoenix, I always see that Phoenix add an extra column (named _0) with an empty value in the hbase, this column(_0) is auto generate by phoenix, but I don't need it, like this:

```
ROW    COLUMN+CELL                                                                   
abc    column=F:A,timestamp=1451305685300,value=123                                
abc    column=F:_0, timestamp=1451305685300, value=    　# I want to avoid generate this row
```

Could you tell me how to avoid that? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

> "At create time, to improve query performance, an empty key value is
>   added to the first column family of any existing rows or the default
>   column family if no column families are explicitly defined. Upserts will also add this empty key value. This improves query performance by having a key value column we can guarantee always being there and thus minimizing the amount of data that must be projected and subsequently returned back to the client."

[Apache Phoenix Documentation](https://phoenix.apache.org/language/index.html#create_table)

Comment: Thanks! I got it! But is it really no way to avoid it? The empty key value looks very littery and redundant, ever if designed for performance.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question if that is avoidable:

You could work around the problem by adding the following statements at the end of your sql:

```
ALTER TABLE "<your-table>" ADD "<your-cf>"."_0" VARCHAR(1);
ALTER TABLE "<your-table>" DROP COLUMN "<your-cf>"."_0";
```

You should only do this if you query some table with phoenix but then access the table with another system that is not aware of this phoenix-specific dummy value.